# Ubuntu - Windows 10 - MBR

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, mbr

I realise this question looks like so many others, but its slightly different and I cannot find an answer elsewhere.

Basically I have goosed my MBR numerous times in the past and this time I wanted to ensure all will run smooth.

So I installed Ubuntu along side Windows 10 but need to remove it and install Fedora. So my question is this...

Am I able to fix the MBR before removing the Ubuntu partition?

The solutions I see are to first fire up Windows remove the partition, insert the Windows recovery media and fix the MBR. As mentioned before I have ended up with a dead laptop and had to wipe and restart.

So am I able to first fix the MBR while Ubuntu is still on, then fire up Windows and at this time delete the partition?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As now you have dual-boot-system so I would recommend you NOT TO JUST REMOVE THE UBUNTU Partition as you won't be able to boot Windows because the information pointed by MBR will be gone. As you have poked your MBR so I guess you should follow THESE steps:

1) Booting from the Ubuntu live CDs.

2) Enabling universe repositories - launch System->Administration->Software Sources and check the "Community maintained Open Source software (universe)"

3) Installing the "ms-sys" package - click Applications->Accessories->Terminal and type "sudo apt-get update" and then "sudo apt-get install ms-sys".

4) Finally restore the Windows master boot record by entering the command "ms-sys -w /dev/[drive]", where [drive] is the hard disk whose Windows master boot record you want to restore. You can find out which this is by launching gparted (System->Administration->GNOME Partition Editor) and cycling through the available drives until you find your Windows partition.

NOTE: YOU CAN USE UBUNTU LIVE CD TO RESTORE MBR.

Do Tell me if you find any error while following these steps. If found relevant then please mark STAR to my answer.

Comment: Thanks @selah1936. I will give this a go now and update.

Comment: sure :) I hope your problem gets solved..

Comment: Thanks for you help. However, I did take a different solution to the problem, which I will post as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I was given the answer over at AskUbuntu. I thought I would share here in case any body else sees this thread.

The answer was posted by 'Byte Commander' "If you add Fedora again, that will also install GRUB again and overwrite the MBR. So I think there's no advantage in installing the Windows bootloader to the MBR first. However, if you really want to first remove Ubuntu and GRUB and restore the Windows bootloader, you have to follow this: askubuntu.com/q/133533/367990 – Byte Commander"

Follow this link if you would like to give him credit with an upvote. https://askubuntu.com/questions/787249/ubuntu-windows-10-mbr/787261#787261

The solution is here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on